# How to replace values in one DataFrames in Python with values from another DataFrames where the dates (in datetime format) matches?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, python-datetime

Given I have two DataFrames:

```
import pandas as pd                                                                                                  

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['2017', '1'], 
                    ['2018', '2'], 
                    ['2019', '3'], 
                    ['2020', '4'], 
                    ['2021', '5'], 
                    ['2022', '6'], 
                    ], columns=['datetime', 'values'])     

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['2018', '0'], 
                    ['2019', '0'], 
                    ['2020', '0'],  
                    ], columns=['datetime', 'values']) 
print(df1)
print(df2)
```

(Assume the values in the column 'datetime' has datetime format and is not string)
How can I replace the values in df1 to the values of df2 where the datetime exists in both without using loops?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) after temporarily setting the index to whatever you want to use as matching columns:

```
(df2.set_index('datetime')
    .combine_first(df1.set_index('datetime'))
    .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
  datetime values
0     2017      1
1     2018      0
2     2019      0
3     2020      0
4     2021      5
5     2022      6
```

Comment: For some reason when I apply it to my actual DataFrame where there are more columns and the 'datetime' column format is not string, it concatenates the dataframes on top of each other!

Comment: @Sh4shayan with the provided sample or another one? This is expected if you have different elements in the two datetime columns (or if the type is different)